# Regular expression to remove ellipses

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to remove the dots at the end of the `stname` column, but nothing I am trying is working.

This is what the dataset looks like.

```
df = structure(list(stname = c("Alabama……………………………………", 
"Alaska………………………………………", "American Samoa……………………………", 
"Arizona………………………………………", "Arkansas……………………………………", 
"California………………………………"), value = c(34305795, 
20236292, 103657, 267021650, 15045025, 3976908430)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried the following but the dots are still there.

```
library(tidyverse)
#remove non alpha-numeric characters
df %>%
  mutate(stname = str_replace_all(stname, "[^[:alnum:][:space:]]", ""))

#remove dots
df %>%
  mutate(stname = str_replace(stname, "\\.+", ""))
```

Neither of those approaches worked.

Comment: `…` does not look like a regular dot `.`

Comment: You can use `trimws(df$stname, "right", "…")`.  As noted above, this is a single character, horizontal ellipsis (`\U2026`).

Comment: @RitchieSacramento the code in your comment worked for me, thank you.

Comment: you can also try: df %>%
  mutate(stname = str_replace_all(stname, "\\.", ""))

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that it's not an actual dot in your stname column. You have a horizontal ellipsis there (P.S. check ansi chars table, this will be number 133: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html)

That's why in your regex you also need to search for horizontal ellipsis. Try to run this, it should help:

mutate(stname = str_replace(stname, "…+", ""))